# Getting invalid oauth access token while trying to retrieve Facebook user profile in Laravel 4

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-4, access-token, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to retrieve user's facebook profile. I am using Laravel 4 framework. Bur I am getting "Invalid oauth access token" every time.

My code is given below.

```
    <?php
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

class FacebookController extends BaseController{
    public function __construct(){
        session_start();
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xx','yy');
    }
    //when the user clicks on the login button he comes to this function
    public function getLogin(){
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(url('facebook/user'));
        return Redirect::to($helper->getLoginUrl());
    }
    //when the user logs in, he comes to this function
    public function getUser(){ 
        try{
            $session = new FacebookSession(Session::get('_token'));//I believe here lies the problem

            $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
            $response = $request->execute();
            $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
            dd($graphObject);
        } catch(Exception $e){
            dd($e);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take a look at the working code we are testing at http://valoresdovale.com/login/fb:

```
<?php

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

session_start(); //this can be moved to app/public/index.php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('login/fb', function() {


    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('YOUR_ID', 'YOUR_SECRET');
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://yoururl/login/fb/callback');
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
    return "<a href='$loginUrl'>facebook</a>";
});

Route::get('login/fb/callback', function() {
// A FacebookResponse is returned from an executed FacebookRequest
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://yoururl/login/fb/callback');
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    try {
        $response = $request->execute();
        $me = $response->getGraphObject();
    } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }

    print_r($me);//->getProperty("id"));
    $user = new Giftee;
    $user->name = $me->getProperty('first_name') . ' ' . $me->getProperty('last_name');
    $user->email    = $me->getProperty('email') . "@facebook.com.br";
    $user->photo    = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $me->getProperty('id') . '/picture?type=large';

    $user->save();

});
```

This was based on http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/integrating-facebook-login-into-laravel-application/ and updated to the new Facebook SDK by [Denisson Leal](https://www.facebook.com/denissonleal).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `session_start()`, laravel will handle all of that session management for you.

It doesn't seem like a laravel-specific problem, but like a simple error in your code:

The example on facebook's documentation page uses `FacebookRedirectLoginHelper::getSessionFromRedirect()` to retrieve the session with which to handle the request(s).

```php
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

    // your old code
}
```

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0)

Comment: It gives me the error missing argument 1 for FacebookRedirectLoginHelper

Comment: Neither [https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/master/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php#L133](getSessionFromRedirect) nor the constructor require arguments. Furthermore the error message sounds very strange because  `FacebookRedirectLoginHelper` is a class, not a function.

Comment: thank you for your help. btw, the constructor requires an argument.