# Laravel, Facebook API: retrieving friends of friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, laravel-4

In a [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225664/laravel-4-getting-invalid-oauth-access-token-while-trying-to-retrieve-facebook/25327945#25327945) we were strugling with the Facebook login using a Laravel app. Now, as the user logs into our app using Facebook, we are trying to get his friend's list in order to provide some qualified suggestions. So, here's what we are trying:

```
Route::get('login/fb/callback', function() {
// A FacebookResponse is returned from an executed FacebookRequest
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://yoururl/login/fb/callback');
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/friends');
    try {
        $response = $request->execute();
        $me = $response->getGraphObject();
    } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }

    print_r($me);//->getProperty("id"));
    $user = new Giftee;
    $user->name = $me->getProperty('first_name') . ' ' . $me->getProperty('last_name');
    $user->email    = $me->getProperty('email') . "@facebook.com.br";
    $user->photo    = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $me->getProperty('id') . '/picture?type=large';

    $user->save();

});
```

As a result, we get:

```
object(Facebook\GraphObject)#146 (1) { ["backingData":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

By reading the Facebook API docs, they pretty much say user_friends will only return friends of friends that already use your app and We could not see any login permission that would just return friends of friends (not only the ones using our app). In another words, is what we want really impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not able to retrieve friends of friends. With Graph API v2.0, you even only get those friends of your app's users which also use your app.

And, all `friends_*` permissions have been removed. So I don't see a chance for you to implement what you want to achieve.