# How to Get facebook friendlist in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

how to get facebook `friendlist` in laravel when user login by facebook login. Already I get the name, email. But I want `frienlist` also. Here is my existing code.

```
public function redirectToProvider()
    {

       return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $socialize_user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

        $facebook_user_id = $socialize_user->getId(); // unique facebook user id
        $facebook_name = $socialize_user->getName();
        $facebook_email = $socialize_user->getEmail();
        $facebook_image = $socialize_user->getAvatar();

        $user = Register::where('facebook_id', $facebook_user_id)->first();

        if ($user) {
            Session::put('id',$user->id);
            Session::put('name',$user->name);
            return redirect::to('welcome');
        }

        // register (if no user)
        if (!$user) {
            $user = new Register;
            $user->facebook_id = $facebook_user_id;
            $user->name = $facebook_name;
            $user->email = $facebook_email;
            $user->image = $facebook_image;
            $user->save();
            return redirect('welcome');
        }

    }
```

Comment: I see that in [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428106/laravel-facebook-api-retrieving-friends-of-friends) someone was trying to get a list of friends of friends which turned out to be impossible, but maybe in their existing code you'll be able to find something that helps you get the basic friends list.

Answer (score 0):

*Before anything you will need the user permission, even if they have already signed in*

**Short version:**

You can't with only socialite or without adding few classes.

**Long version:**

You need to extend FacebookProvider and implement the user interface.

This is the [user interface of the user](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/3.0/src/Contracts/User.php) so you can add the friend list method.

And this is the [FacebookProvider](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/3.0/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php) which includes the required authentication for accessing the facebook state and token, you can read on the loginFlow process [on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow).

To get access to the user friend list, you need to get the user permission, hence you need to initiate the full process again and add the user permission or add it at the start of the process.

**Quick version:**

If it is only for the friend list, better to use JavaScript and add friend list permission, and then use the response that you get, [facebook graph api JS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples#graphapi).

**Laravel version:**

check this package from [sammyK](https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk) it gives you great control on FacebookPHPSDK if you want more functions.